# Progress Bar File Upload - Without AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I'm attempting to get the upload progress from a file upload that I have programmed. The default upload progress (bottom left of browser) comes up and im trying to replicate this.

My PHP uploader works like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['fileUploadProcess'])) {

    define ("filesplace","./voucher-portal/");
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {

        if ($_FILES['file']['type'] != "application/pdf") {
            ?>
            //refuse anything but pdf
            <?php
} else {
        $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], filesplace."/$name.pdf");
        }
        if ($result == 1) 
            ?>
           //echo works or not
```

The uploading process all works mighty fine, however a progress bar is a must and I cant seem to find anything that I can incorporate with my PHP method of file uploading.

NOTE: I'm using this method as I rename the file and place it in a certain directory with database driven vairables

Comment: the progress is managed by the javascript its not serverside.... try to post your upload code ( an ajax i guess )

Comment: if you want without AJAX, but AJAX provides a good solution already, it woudl make sense to explain why you don't want to use that.

Comment: @hoijui Hi, I mention in the note why, I can use AJAX for the purpose of progress though, but not sure how this will be possible!

Comment: so the reason is that you can not access your DB from within AJAX and thus it could not know where to store the files to? i admit that i have very little knowledge about all this stuff, sorry, but the lack of answers or other commenters suggests that your problem seems to be very unclear to others aswell, so you would have to explain at least this part much better (probably also with more code to help understanding).